# DAX value = IF(AND(OR(...)))

Tags: powerbi, dax

I find myself needing a function that will provide a value return based on a text marker my BI tables. There are two columns that contain the basis for my statement.

Column - `StatusTypeCode` with multiple values. 
The two I am wanting to use for the `OR` statement are `'AutoApprv'` and `'Approved'`

Column - `CreateUserID_1` with multiple values 
I am using `--LEFT(CreateUserID_1,3)="pid")`

I have my `IF(AND` statement working well.

```
Auto_Count = IF(AND([StatusTypeCode]="AutoApprv",LEFT([CreateUserID_1],3)="pid"),1,0)
```

I want to add another variable dimension into the `StatusTypeCode` of `"Approve"`.  I was thinking an `IF(AND(OR` but cannot seem to get the syntax correct, if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
Auto_Count = IF(
                 AND(
                     OR(
                         [StatusTypeCode] = "AutoApprv",
                         [StatusTypeCode] = "Approve"
                       ),
                     LEFT([CreateUserID_1],3) = "pid"
                    ),
                 1,
                 0
               )
```